# change the fontsize of text and space between columns in a table

Tags: tables, spacing, fontsize

I try to make a table to a two columns document but the space between columns and the **fontsize** in the table is big and extend more than the space I would like to fill. How could I reduce the space between columns a bit and change the fontsize of the text in the table ?

```
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}*4c@{}}
  \toprule[1.5pt]
 & BIAS &  $\sigma$& OUT.[$\%$] \\
\hline
Five (17$\leq$ R $<$ 21) &-0.0099$\pm$0.0001&0.0004$\pm$0.05&0.003$\pm$0.0001 \\

Seventeen&0.0008$\pm$0.007&0.07$\pm$0.0004&0.0002$\pm$0.073\\
Five (21$\leq$ R $<$ 23)&-0.053$\pm$0.0015&0.0002$\pm$0.04&1.002$\pm$0.006\\
Seventeen&0.0001$\pm$0.01&0.007$\pm$0.004&0.0011$\pm$0.04\\
\bottomrule[1.5pt]
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**update:** Based on the given answer, I made another table

```
\usepackage[separate-uncertainty,input-comparators]{siunitx}    
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{The results }
\centering
\begin{tabular}{
         l
         S[table-format = -1.(1)]
         S[table-format =  1.4]
         S[table-format =  1.4]
         S[table-format =  1.4]
               }
\toprule[1.5pt]
APPROACH       & {BIAS} &{$\sigma$} & {OUT. [\si{\percent}]} &{ODDS CUT}\\
\midrule
\textit{local} & -0.05  & 0.9       & 14.5                   &\num{\ge0.0}\\
\textit{global}&  0.28  & 0.1       & 51.4                   &\num{\ge0.0}\\
\midrule
\textit{local}& -0.6   & 0.21      & 1.7                    &\num{\ge0.95}\\
\textit{global}& 0.3   & 0.29      & 10.2                   &\num{\ge0.95}\\
\bottomrule[1.5pt]
\end{tabular}
\label{tab:ps}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I get an error saying:

```
! siunitx error: "invalid-token-in-number"
!
! Invalid token '\ge ' in numerical input.
!
```

Comment: please fix your example so that people can process it with latex, and to know the required column width (I assume this is a two column document, you don't say)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle well it is a format of a journal and I don't know how I should fix my example here?!!

Comment: Your original document isn't that relevant to be honest but the code example is no use at all if people can not run it, just make a two column article class document and adjust the text width if necessary to show your problem, see http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225/1090

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I would do it, using the [`siunitx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[separate-uncertainty]{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\small                    % change according to needs
\setlength\tabcolsep{6pt} % change according to needs
\centering
  \begin{tabular}{
         l
         S[table-format = -1.4(1)]
    *{2}{S[table-format =  1.4(1)]}
  }
   \toprule
                            & {BIAS}             & {$\sigma$}        & {OUT. [\si{\percent}]} \\
   \midrule
    Five ($17 \leq R < 21$) & -0.0099 \pm 0.0001 & 0.0004 \pm 0.05   & 0.003  \pm 0.0001      \\
    Seventeen               &  0.0008 \pm 0.007  & 0.07   \pm 0.0004 & 0.0002 \pm 0.073       \\
    Five ($21 \leq R < 23$) & -0.053  \pm 0.0015 & 0.0002 \pm 0.04   & 1.002  \pm 0.006       \\
    Seventeen               &  0.0001 \pm 0.01   & 0.007  \pm 0.004  & 0.0011 \pm 0.04        \\
   \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: output1]

**Update**

Generally it's better to declare repeated symbols (unit, ect.) within a table column in---or just below---the header; it eases the reading.

Here is one option:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{spacing}{:\quad}
\captionsetup{
labelsep = spacing,
figureposition = bottom,
tableposition = top,
font = small,
labelfont = sc
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{The results.}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{
l
S[table-format = -1.2]
S[table-format =  1.2]
S[table-format =  2.1]
S[table-format =  1.2]
}
\toprule
APPROACH       & {BIAS} &{$\sigma$} & {OUT. [\si{\percent}]} & {ODDS CUT ($\ge$)} \\
\midrule
\textit{local} & -0.05  & 0.9       & 14.5                   & 0.0                \\
\textit{global}&  0.28  & 0.1       & 51.4                   & 0.0                \\
\midrule
\textit{local} & -0.6   & 0.21      &  1.7                   & 0.95               \\
\textit{global}&  0.3   & 0.29      & 10.2                   & 0.95               \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: output2]

Comment: with which parameter could I reduce the space between columns or decrease the size?

Comment: @Dalek Please read the comments in the code.

Comment: How could I use comparison (`>` or `<`) symbols in this table when I use `siunitx`? I get errors when I use comparison symbols inside the above table format.

Comment: Please update your question with an example of what you want, e.g. a picture. I'm not sure I understand your.

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: Updated answer. Next time, please create another question since it isn't about the same table.